# Laravel Sail build failed on M1 mac

Tags: laravel, docker, apple-m1, laravel-sail

I'm trying to build the 'laravel.test' docker image on my new macbook pro with the M1 Pro chip, but I'm getting this error:

```
=> ERROR [ 5/12] RUN apt-get update     && apt-get install -y gnupg gosu curl ca-certificates zip unzip git sup  21.5s
------
 > [ 5/12] RUN apt-get update     && apt-get install -y gnupg gosu curl ca-certificates zip unzip git supervisor sqlite3 libcap2-bin libpng-dev python2     && mkdir -p ~/.gnupg     && chmod 600 ~/.gnupg     && echo "disable-ipv6" >> ~/.gnupg/dirmngr.conf     && apt-key adv --homedir ~/.gnupg --keyserver hkps://keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 14AA40EC0831756756D7F66C4F4EA0AAE5267A6C     && echo "deb https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu impish main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ppa_ondrej_php.list     && apt-get update     && apt-get install -y php8.1-cli php8.1-dev        php8.1-pgsql php8.1-sqlite3 php8.1-gd        php8.1-curl        php8.1-imap php8.1-mysql php8.1-mbstring        php8.1-xml php8.1-zip php8.1-bcmath php8.1-soap        php8.1-intl php8.1-readline        php8.1-ldap        php8.1-msgpack php8.1-igbinary php8.1-redis php8.1-swoole        php8.1-memcached php8.1-pcov php8.1-xdebug     && php -r "readfile('https://getcomposer.org/installer');" | php -- --install-dir=/usr/bin/ --filename=composer     && curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_16.x | bash -     && apt-get install -y nodejs     && npm install -g npm     && curl -sS https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | apt-key add -     && echo "deb https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ stable main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list     && echo "deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt impish-pgdg main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list     && curl --silent -o - https://www.postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc | apt-key add -     && apt-get update     && apt-get install -y yarn     && apt-get install -y mysql-client     && apt-get install -y postgresql-client     && apt-get -y autoremove     && apt-get clean     && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*:
#8 10.35 Hit:1 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports impish InRelease
#8 10.39 Hit:2 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports impish-updates InRelease
#8 10.45 Hit:3 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports impish-backports InRelease
#8 10.51 Hit:4 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports impish-security InRelease
#8 10.56 Reading package lists...
#8 10.89 Reading package lists...
#8 11.20 Building dependency tree...
#8 11.27 Reading state information...
#8 11.35 ca-certificates is already the newest version (20210119ubuntu1).
#8 11.35 curl is already the newest version (7.74.0-1.3ubuntu2).
#8 11.35 gnupg is already the newest version (2.2.20-1ubuntu4).
#8 11.35 libcap2-bin is already the newest version (1:2.44-1build1).
#8 11.35 libpng-dev is already the newest version (1.6.37-3build4).
#8 11.35 sqlite3 is already the newest version (3.35.5-1).
#8 11.35 unzip is already the newest version (6.0-26ubuntu1).
#8 11.35 zip is already the newest version (3.0-12build1).
#8 11.35 gosu is already the newest version (1.12-1build1).
#8 11.35 python2 is already the newest version (2.7.18-3).
#8 11.35 supervisor is already the newest version (4.2.1-1ubuntu1).
#8 11.35 git is already the newest version (1:2.32.0-1ubuntu1.1).
#8 11.35 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 4 not upgraded.
#8 11.38 Warning: apt-key is deprecated. Manage keyring files in trusted.gpg.d instead (see apt-key(8)).
#8 11.39 Executing: /tmp/apt-key-gpghome.z6BHPockHd/gpg.1.sh --homedir /root/.gnupg --keyserver hkps://keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 14AA40EC0831756756D7F66C4F4EA0AAE5267A6C
#8 21.44 gpg: keyserver receive failed: Server indicated a failure
------
failed to solve: executor failed running [/bin/sh -c apt-get update     && apt-get install -y gnupg gosu curl ca-certificates zip unzip git supervisor sqlite3 libcap2-bin libpng-dev python2     && mkdir -p ~/.gnupg     && chmod 600 ~/.gnupg     && echo "disable-ipv6" >> ~/.gnupg/dirmngr.conf     && apt-key adv --homedir ~/.gnupg --keyserver hkps://keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 14AA40EC0831756756D7F66C4F4EA0AAE5267A6C     && echo "deb https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu impish main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ppa_ondrej_php.list     && apt-get update     && apt-get install -y php8.1-cli php8.1-dev        php8.1-pgsql php8.1-sqlite3 php8.1-gd        php8.1-curl        php8.1-imap php8.1-mysql php8.1-mbstring        php8.1-xml php8.1-zip php8.1-bcmath php8.1-soap        php8.1-intl php8.1-readline        php8.1-ldap        php8.1-msgpack php8.1-igbinary php8.1-redis php8.1-swoole        php8.1-memcached php8.1-pcov php8.1-xdebug     && php -r "readfile('https://getcomposer.org/installer');" | php -- --install-dir=/usr/bin/ --filename=composer     && curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_$NODE_VERSION.x | bash -     && apt-get install -y nodejs     && npm install -g npm     && curl -sS https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | apt-key add -     && echo "deb https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ stable main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list     && echo "deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt impish-pgdg main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list     && curl --silent -o - https://www.postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc | apt-key add -     && apt-get update     && apt-get install -y yarn     && apt-get install -y mysql-client     && apt-get install -y postgresql-client     && apt-get -y autoremove     && apt-get clean     && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*]: exit code: 2
```

ps: the image is running well on my old macbook pro with the intel chip

this happens after I run the following
./vendor/bin/sail up -d

Sail Version: 1.13.9

Laravel Version: 8.83.8

PHP Version: 8.1.4

OS: macOS 12.3.1

Comment: for anyone who's still struggling with this, [this comment](https://github.com/laravel/sail/issues/383#issuecomment-1100387453) on the official Sail repo seems to solve the problem for now, while waiting for the maintainers to raise a PR for it.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue. It seems like the DNS resolution failed for some reason. I changed the DNS Server IP of my computer to 8.8.8.8 (Google) or 1.1.1.1 (Cloudflare) and it solved the problem.

It only happens when you have to build the Docker Image. Maybe it works on your old computer because you have a previous build on it or a different DNS settings. Try to rebuild it with sail build --no-cache on your old macbook. If you get the same error, maybe it's your DNS cache on your router or something in your DNS lookup chain. If it succeed, look at your DNS settings to compare with your new macbook.